# How to pass an object to a class that will be injected later

Tags: java, oop, guice, guice-3

I am pretty new to google guice .

I am writing a nexus plugin where nexus injects some classes . for example say the class to be injected in **class A**.

Now before that class A is injected, I have another **class B** that was instantiated and inside it I have a method where an object (say obj) is initialised .

I have to pass this initialised object to the class A.

Normally if instantiation is under our control I will do as

```
A a = new A();

A.setObject(obj);
```

But now given that the class will be injected by the system , I don't know how to pass this initialised object to this class A.

Comment: `A` will have an `obj` injected property.

Comment: How will it know that obj is from this class ?

Comment: Can you write code snippet and explain as an answer ? pls

Comment: I am not Guice expert but with other DI I use the answer would be that you can only inject instances created by the DI framework, and not instances created outside it. This leaves two ways: a) retrieve the object in a `@PostConstruct` method from `A` that retrieves `B` instance or b) code a Factory method that creates the `B` instance you want and use it to inject the property.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have something like

```
public class C {
}

public class A {
    private C c;

    public void setC(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}

public class B {
    private final C c;

    public B() {
        this.c = new C();
    }

    public C getC() {
        return this.c;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        A a = new A();

        C c = b.getC();
        a.setC(c);
    }
}
```

This design does not follow DI principles and should be refactored. You should let Guice create your `C` instance. In that case you will have something like

```
public class C {
}

public class A {
    private final C c;

    @Inject
    A(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}

public class B {
    private final C c;

    @Inject
    B(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
        A a = injector.getInstance(A.class);
        B b = injector.getInstance(B.class);
    }
}
```

And here you have `C` automatically injected both into `A` and `B`.

If you *really* cannot refactor you code, consider using providers then:

```
public class AProvider extends Provider<A> {
    private final B b;

    @Inject
    AProvider(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public A get() {
        A a = new A();
        C c = b.getC();
        a.setC(c);
        // Or, better
        // A a = new A(b.getC());
        return a;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(A.class).toProvider(AProvider.class);
            }
        });
        A a = injector.getInstance(A.class);
    }
}
```

In this case a provider is used to create `A` and set its `C` dependency.

But sometimes even that is not enough (e.g. when your `B.getC()` behavior depends on user input). In that case you have to use [assisted inject](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject) extension:

```
public interface AFactory {
    public A create(C c);
}

public class A {
    private final C c;
    private final Other other;

    @Inject
    A(@Assisted C c, Other other) {
        this.c = c;
        this.other = other;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Inject
            protected void configure() {
                install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
                    .build(AFactory.class));
            }
        });

        B b = injector.getInstance(B.class);
        C c = b.getC(someUserInput);
        AFactory af = injector.getInstance(AFactory.class);
        A a = af.create(c);
    }
}
```

In the last example two object will be injected into `A` via `af.create(c)` invocation: first, that `c` you have provided, and second, and instance of `Other` class which is resolved automatically by Guice. In other words, assisted inject allows you to instantiate classes which will have one part of their dependencies resolved by you, and other part - by Guice.